# Go autocert acme/autocert: missing server name

Tags: go, ssl, tls1.2, lets-encrypt

I use library *autocert* in my application for generating an SSL certificate. The problem is 30% of users have a problem with my application. My current code is:

```
fmt.Println("Starting server on " + this.Params.Bind)
if this.Params.SSL {
    fmt.Println("SSL Enabled")
    m := autocert.Manager{
        Prompt:     autocert.AcceptTOS,
        HostPolicy: autocert.HostWhitelist(this.Params.HostsWhitelist...),
        Cache:      autocert.DirCache(this.Params.CertCache),
    }

    log.Fatal(autotls.RunWithManager(r, &m))
} else {
    r.Run(this.Params.Bind)
}
```

The errors are:

```
2018/12/03 12:37:33 http: TLS handshake error from 68.71.48.249:55885: acme/autocert: missing server name
2018/12/03 12:37:33 http: TLS handshake error from 209.213.121.223:38284: acme/autocert: missing server name
2018/12/03 12:37:33 http: TLS handshake error from 209.213.121.223:38283: acme/autocert: missing server name
2018/12/03 12:37:33 http: TLS handshake error from 68.71.48.249:55887: acme/autocert: missing server name
2018/12/03 12:37:33 http: TLS handshake error from 68.71.48.249:55888: acme/autocert: missing server name
2018/12/03 12:37:33 http: TLS handshake error from 209.237.150.145:56842: acme/autocert: missing server name
```

How can I fix the error with the missing server name?

Comment: Looks like your clients don't support [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). If you want to host multiple domains on the same IP:port pair, that's nothing you can fix on the server.